# Trying to replicate basic bash pipe but i get a stdin: Input/output error

Tags: c, pipe, fork, dup2

I am currently working on a university project to basically built my own simple shell. Everything is working great so far. The only thing giving me trouble is pipes. To make it easier for myself to figure out why they are not working as intended I wrote this little testing program where I try to replicate the bash behaviour of `cat | ls`. But i now sadly get this error  `cat: stdin: Input/output error` and i really can't figure it out.

Here is my program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     main(void)
{
    extern char **environ;
    char *argv1[] = {"cat",NULL};
    char *argv2[] = {"ls",NULL};
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    int ret;

    pipe(fd);
    pid = fork();
    if  (pid == 0) 
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        execve("/bin/cat", argv1, environ);
        exit (0);
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[1], STDIN_FILENO);
        execve("/bin/ls", argv2, environ);
        waitpid(pid, &ret, 0);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: For `ls`: `close(fd[1])` --> `close(fd[0])`

Comment: But after any `dup2(X,...)` you should do: `close(X)`

Comment: If you `exit` after `execv*`, you should `exit(1)`.  The only way `exec*` returns is if it failed.  If it fails, you should return non-zero.  Better yet, use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`

Comment: You cannot `waitpid` after `execve`.  (Well, you can, but the `waitpid` will only be executed if `execve` fails.) You can't do anything after `execve`.  If you want to continue processing after `ls` exits, you'll need to `fork` twice; one child runs `cat` and one child runs `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

You want a pipe like:

```
ls | cat
```

But, you're setting this up like:

```
cat | ls
```

And, in your current code, for the `ls` side, you're doing:

```
close(fd[1]);
dup2(fd[1], STDIN_FILENO);
```

This is wrong for two reasons:

1. You're closing the wrong side of the pipe, so the `dup2` gets a closed fd as its first argument
2. You're attaching the *output* side of the pipe to the command's *input* side

So, we need to reverse the pipe order and fix the closing.

Also, after doing `dup2(X,...)` we want to do `close(X)`.

Also, note that doing `waitpid` _after `execve` will have *no* effect unless the `execve` fails.

Here is the refactored and working code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int
main(void)
{
    extern char **environ;
    char *argv_cat[] = { "cat", NULL };
    char *argv_ls[] = { "ls", NULL };
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    int ret;

    pipe(fd);

    pid = fork();

    // we want:
    //   ls | cat
    if (pid == 0) {
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        execve("/bin/cat", argv_cat, environ);
        exit(0);
    }

    else if (pid > 0) {
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[1]);
        execve("/bin/ls", argv_ls, environ);
        waitpid(pid, &ret, 0);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> `waitpid` after `execve` is pointless. –
> William Pursell

Not quite. It reaps the [stuck] child process so that it doesn't become a child of the `init/systemd` process.

In the above example, I had forgotten to add a `close(STDOUT_FILENO)` before the `waitpid` to "release" the `cat` process.

Here is the adjusted code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int opt_f;

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    extern char **environ;
    char *argv_cat[] = { "cat", NULL };
    char *argv_ls[] = { "ls", NULL };
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'f':
            opt_f = ! opt_f;
            break;
        }
    }

    pipe(fd);

    pid = fork();

    // we want:
    //   ls | cat
    if (pid == 0) {
        if (opt_f)
            fprintf(stderr,"cld: getpid=%d\n",getpid());
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        execve("/bin/cat", argv_cat, environ);
        exit(0);
    }

    else if (pid > 0) {
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[1]);

        const char *ls = opt_f ? "/bin/gooch" : "/bin/ls";
        execve(ls, argv_ls, environ);

        fprintf(stderr,"execve failure of '%s' -- %s\n",ls,strerror(errno));

        // release other process (cat)
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);

        // reap the child
        pid_t ret = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

        fprintf(stderr,"ret=%d pid=%d status=%8.8X\n",ret,pid,status);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `waitpid` after `execve` is pointless.

Comment: @WilliamPursell No, not quite. See my update.